# How to kill another app if your app has Device Admin/ Device Owner permission ( not rooted )

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, device-admin, device-owner, samsung-knox

How can I kill ( or prevent the launch ) another app from my application if mine has Device Admin/ Device Owner permission ( not rooted ) ?

Answer (score 2):

A device owner can block applications :

[`DevicePolicyManager.setPackagesSuspended()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setPackagesSuspended(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean)) : The application icon is greyed, and the user can not launch it,  a message *This application has been suspended by your administrator* is displayed instead.

[`DevicePolicyManager.setApplicationHidden()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setApplicationHidden(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) : The application does not even appear in the launcher.

In both cases the application is not uninstalled and it's data is not deleted. As soon as you unhide / unsuspend it, the user will be able to use it again and pick  up where they left off